# How to show event title and time in calendar block?

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I have create a view based on the template. The events are shown up properly as a link in the calendar block:

[image]

How to I add also the event name and time (similar to the month page)? i.e.:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you would like to add the event name and time to the calendar you have provided on the top? If that's what you're asking, I don't think you can, and that is what the month page is there for. In Views, can you make the month page a block instead and place that wherever you need it?

Comment: How can I _"make the month page a block"_?

Comment: Go to Structure -> Views -> Calendar and then click on the tab at the top under "Displays" that says "Month." Next, click the "+Add" tab and select Block. This should create a block that is a copy of the Month page, and then you can put this block in whatever region you'd like.

Comment: Tried. The newly created block shows nothing in preview.

Comment: Ah, then I'm _guessing_ it's not being styled then, and you would maybe have to manually style it (or check the various settings of the other one and the new block to see if there are any custom CSS selectors you should add. Otherwise, you _may_ be able to style it yourself. Unfortunately I don't have access to a site at the moment where I can play around and experiment with Calendar, or I'd look into it further.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Structure -> Views -> Calendar View` and then under `Displays` click `Block`. Next, under heading `Format` click `Settings` next to **`Format: Calendar`** and choose **`No`** for ***`Display as mini calendar`***